# PARTIALLY SOLVED - Visual Studio 2019 is Publishing two folders with two almost idenical EXE's and linking to the wrong one

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, publish, mdf

I have written a project in Visual Studio using good old VB Forms.
The project calls a web API to get data and stores it in a local MDF file, using SQL commands. It all works in Debug mode, but my first few attempts to Publish it failed as there where no MDF files published with the project. (I am using One Click Publish)

After a bit of digging around, I found a reccommendation to tag the MDF and LDF files as "Content" so that they are included when Publishing. After publishing the project and running Setup, the program still tries to run and fails as it cannot find the SQL file.

When I look at the install location, there is no MDF file, however, there is an almost identical folder, with almost identical files, that also has the EXE file, along with the necessary MDF and LDF files. If I run the EXE in *that* folder, the software works as required.

Listing of Install Location showing two folders:

```
     Directory of C:\Users\Craig\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\WLM3TYKE.PNN\11MC5949.Y3N

05/10/2021  03:05 PM    <DIR>          .
05/10/2021  03:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/10/2021  12:28 AM    <DIR>          manifests
05/10/2021  12:28 AM    <DIR>          xilo..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_36cca78f00949ccf
05/10/2021  12:28 AM    <DIR>          xilog4.exe_0000000000000000_0001.0000_none_877f6059e612404d
```

The link in the Windows Start Menu points to the EXE in the folder that fails on start up.

If I uninstall the program, both folders are deleted. If I reinstall, both folders come back.

Listing of Folder 1, that does not work:

```
     Directory of C:\Users\Craig\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\WLM3TYKE.PNN\11MC5949.Y3N\xilo..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_36cca78f00949ccf

05/10/2021  03:09 PM    <DIR>          .
05/10/2021  03:09 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           150,408 Azure.Core.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           213,888 Azure.Identity.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM             2,884 Launcher.cdf-ms
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            14,336 Launcher.exe
05/10/2021  12:28 AM               972 Launcher.manifest
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            14,712 Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           364,008 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM         1,310,152 Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            52,600 Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            62,840 Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            24,952 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            32,632 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           108,920 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           870,264 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           695,336 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM    <DIR>          runtimes
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            81,784 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            83,528 System.Runtime.Caching.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            22,252 Xilog4.deps.json
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            20,992 Xilog4.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           142,336 Xilog4.exe
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            26,788 Xilog4.exe.cdf-ms
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            14,313 Xilog4.exe.manifest
05/10/2021  12:28 AM               154 Xilog4.runtimeconfig.json
```

Listing of Folder 2, that does work:

```
     Directory of C:\Users\Craig\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\WLM3TYKE.PNN\11MC5949.Y3N\xilog4.exe_0000000000000000_0001.0000_none_877f6059e612404d

05/10/2021  03:10 PM    <DIR>          .
05/10/2021  03:10 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           150,408 Azure.Core.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           213,888 Azure.Identity.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            14,712 Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           364,008 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM         1,310,152 Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            52,600 Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            62,840 Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            24,952 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            32,632 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           108,920 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           870,264 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           695,336 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM    <DIR>          runtimes
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            81,784 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            83,528 System.Runtime.Caching.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            22,252 Xilog4.deps.json
05/10/2021  12:28 AM            20,992 Xilog4.dll
05/10/2021  12:28 AM           142,336 Xilog4.exe
05/10/2021  12:28 AM               154 Xilog4.runtimeconfig.json
05/10/2021  12:28 AM         8,388,608 XilogData.mdf
05/10/2021  12:28 AM         8,388,608 XilogData_log.ldf
```

So ... why two folders? How do I set up the Publish only one folder, the one with the required database files?

Answer (score 0):

Applied the following steps

- Deleted the One Click Publishing Profile
- Added another One Click Publishing Profile
- Under "Settings" Select "Applications Files" and click "Show All Files"
- For the MDF and LDF files, change Publish Status to "Include"

Still Publishes to two locations, but the linked location now has the MDF and LDF file and the program runs.